# Does Flyway support DB2 for zOS?

Tags: db2, flyway, zos

Does Flyway support DB2 for zOS?
The information here http://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/db2.html seems to indicate it is only tested on DB2 for LUW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has not been tested. Please give it a try and let me know how it went! Feel free to file any problems you encounter in the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

It can't work as written for Db2 for Z as there is a system table that LUW has that Z does not have.   It would be really nice to have this in the Z environment.